# tmux changes shell prompt

Tags: shell, tmux, prompt, fish

```
Ubuntu 20.04 (running inside VirtualBox, if that's important.)
tmux 3.0a (installed via apt)
fish 3.4 (and  earlier 3.3)
starship.rs 1.1.1 
Font: FiraCode Mono
```

I have configured my prompt to look as follows, by default:

[image: default prompt with fish and starship.rs]

However when I start tmux it changes to:

[image: prompt after running tmux]

I have another laptop with the same pieces of software, except all of it runs under WSL2 and  I use Windows Terminal, where this doesn't happen; the arrow remains after starting `tmux`. Could anyone tell me what's wrong here? Happy to share configs, if required, although `.tmux.conf` doesn't exist, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue -

`tmux -u`

solved it.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem. I would expect something like this to happen in Windows/WSL rather than Ubuntu.